# What is the difference between IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP and IPV6_JOIN_GROUP?

Tags: ipv6, multicast

I notice that most OSes that define IPv6 multicast define two sets of socket options; `IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`/`IPV6_DROP_MEMBERSHIP` and `IPV6_JOIN_GROUP`/`IPV6_LEAVE_GROUP`. Whenever I find them, they are documented as synonyms, taking the same option value. In fact some go as far as to `#define` one to literally mean the other; for example

```
#define IPV6_JOIN_GROUP IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP
```

Is there any difference here, or is it just historical baggage - two names for the same thing?

Comment: Just historical baggage, I think.

Comment: Seems so, see `/usr/include/bits/in.h` on Linux.

Comment: Which is the more modern/preferred? BSD only seems to define IPV6_JOIN_GROUP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're identical. Synonyms, just like you said.